# In Android After Jenkins build, http call to server is not working, if i disable the proguard app will work fine

Tags: android, jenkins

**After Jenkins build, http call to server is not working, if I disable the proguard app will work fine.**

I configure the jenkins job to generate signed apk.

Getting.
Java.lang.RuntypeException:missing type parameter

But same code works fine if I skip proguard execution.

I used third party library org.apache.httpcomponent and com.google.code.gson

**What I have tried?**

Skipped third party api from encryption in progaurd.conf property by fallowing.

-dontwarn org.apache.http.**

-dontwarn com.google.code.**

Why the httpcall is not working with proguard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GSON needs more Proguard configuration. See the official [GSON example](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/examples/android-proguard-example/proguard.cfg) for a full sample config file.